# Unity3D UGUI (aka "new UI") Draw Call Optimization

Tags: unity-game-engine

We recently created an asset that displays data in a table layout in the 'new' (> 4.6) Unity UI.  Some of our users are asking about draw call performance and we are wondering what (if any) options we have to improve draw calls in the UI.

[image: Table Usage GIF]

So the above table sticks pretty consistently at **19 draw calls**...

[image]

It runs fine on anything ipad2-level and above, but Unity dev's (understandably) hate draw calls so we want to minimize that number as much as possible.

You can see the hierarchy we are creating for our table in the above screenshot.  We are using masks for the Header/Footer/Body and the ColumnOverlay.  Per Unity, it appears that each Mask takes a minimum of 2 draws:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-4-6-ui-mask-component-takes-2-draw-calls.279840/

Also, we are obviously using a bunch of the Unity UI Text and Sprite elements to draw everything.  The basic nature of a table layout pretty much means that there are multiple layers of Sprite and Text objects on top of each other (cell data on top of cell background, etc).   Unity dev's seem to say that there's simply no way to NOT have multiple draw calls when this happens as the engine requires a draw per "layer"... period.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-new-ugui-and-too-many-draw-calls.266631/

So... it seems that as soon as you have a non-trivial UI layout in the Unity UI you are pretty much guaranteed to have a non-trivial (10-20) amount of draw calls.  Is that true?  If it isn't, does anyone have any ideas on anything we could do to minimize draws in our table?

### Update 1:

I was able to reduce my draw-calls by one by inactivating a custom 'measure' element I have on each data row.  It's basically a hacked "Text" object but I'm just using it to measure cells for grid sizing and it was taking an extra draw call.  The measure features actually work fine with the GameObject deactivated.

#### Current Draw Calls == 18

### Update 2:

Found a big improvement.  I mentioned above that my Header/Footer/Body and ColumnOverlay all use masks elements.  Turns out, I was able to restructure my system to include a single Mask on a new root-level element and remove the Masks on the Header, Footer, and ColumnOverlay.  Now I just have a Mask on that root element and the Body.

[image: Masks Improvements]

#### Current Draw Calls == 13

### Update 3 [the failures]:

So each row contains that bottom border line image to offset it from it's siblings.  I thought maybe it's printing 'on top' of the Text elements and forcing an extra draw.  Turns out no... it's not.

Also... all my background Image elements have no sprite property defined.  They are just using "null" with a color applied.  I thought maybe if I created a single generic 'white' sprite and applied it to all my null Image objects it might improve batching and reduce my draw calls.  Turns out no... it doesn't.

#### Current Draw Calls == 13

Comment: Are those icons on the same sprite sheet?

Comment: Yep, they are.   As soon as I have some cycles to do so though, I'm going to add all the 'null' sprites to a generic filler sprite and play with that a bit more (the bit I talk about in the 'update 3' above).  I don't believe in this exact case I'm creating extra draw calls with the null sprites but I want to double-check and make sure I didn't miss something there.

Comment: Really handy post.  One general thought is, grab 2DToolkit, which generally "drastically reduces drawcalls", and it may help in some way?  We fool around with it first to see what can be done  :/

Comment: I find it quite impressive that this results in only 13 draw calls. In perfect conditions you'd probably still need 2 since the sprites and fonts won't share a texture. There might be room for improvement for your implementation, but I'd guess you'll need much more effort to achieve a better number.

Comment: One tip--and I'm not sure how to best utilize this in your issue--is to use more canvases. Unity's canvas object has to re-evauluate everything when something changes. If you instead break things out into smaller chunks (child or sibling canvas objects) it reduces the sort complexity,

Comment: Consider using RectMask2D instead of Mask. Also if your images are not being sprite packed, consider turning on sprite packer to reduce further.

Comment: Use sprite packer to reduce draw calls to 1 for all sprites

Answer (score 5):

As I understand your problem is UI batching.

Now I will try to explaine how it works.

When you create an empty scene in Unity you have only one draw call due your camera and your canvas. Lets look to the pic below:

[image]

So when you add new `Image` object to the scene you obtain a new one.

[image]

It is happened because you add a new material to the scene. If you add some more objects with the same materials, they will be batched to the one draw call and not produce new one.

[image]

If you add to the scene an object with a new one material it produced an additional draw call.

[image]

It looks like ok. But if the object with new material located between batched objects in hierarcy and intersect with any of it you will have a problem. You batchig will be separated to the two part and will produce two drow calls.

[image]

So I thik your problem is here. You need to look to you hierarchy closely, and remember, that `Image` and `Text` objects has defferent materials. So each `Text` located between two `Image` objects in heierarcy prodeced additional draw call when text's shape intersect with image's shape.